# Obtain, portably, larger and faster (unsigned) integer type on a platform

Tags: c, c99, portability

Imagine the hypothetical case of a custom arbitrary precision integer type that must run as fast as possible, being fully portable at the same time. To achieve this goal, we need to use the larger and faster (unsigned) integer type available for a given platform.

It must be the larger because this way we will process maximum number of bits per cycle.

It must be the faster because on some platforms there are available larger integer types but with only a subset of integer operations over them (for example, in x86, 128 bit integers doesn't allow to do a one-instruction add-with-carry operation).

What is the best and most portable way to obtain the larger and faster integer type on every platform that has a C99 standard compiler (if it is possible at all)?

Comment: The way the question is asked, it has no answer.   There is no way to portably determine in C code the largest and fastest integer type (even assuming those two characteristics even go together) available on a given platform.   The only way to work such things out involves a human reading relevant documentation for the platform and compiler of interest.

Comment: @Peter This is a valid answer. I never assumed that there is a way t do it...

Comment: `uint_fast64_t`? [http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer)

Comment: Do you know the 256 bits C standard integer type that would require `add-with-carry` instructions to let the compiler generate optimal code for addition? If you speak about portability, then you should make no assumptions on specifics of the target CPU. However, you could include several implementations of the same algorithm that use different integer types to perform arbitrary precision calculations. Then, benchmark them at runtime for a few first calls and set the best implementation to be used for the rest of program run.

Comment: @AlterMann This is not the fastest type on every platform. For example, it will take a minimum of two instructions to execute on x86-32 and four on x86-16.

Comment: @Serge Never before I had read anything about a 256 bit type in standard C99. Can you give us more information?

Comment: Why not `uintmax_t`?  At least with GCC (6.1.0) on Mac OS X 10.11.4, it is an 8-byte (64-bit) type — hence equivalent to `uint64_t` and `unsigned long long` etc — but it is the largest size that the compiler claims is standard conforming.  Using `unsigned __int128` 'works' but has limited support; it is the antithesis of portable, therefore.  Note that in theory different machines could have different sizes for `uintmax_t`, but if the compiler is at least C99 compliant, it will be at least 64 bits.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Because the optimal algorithm for an increment operation on an arbitrary precision integer must need a single arithmetic instruction in its best case. Defining them as an array of `uintmax_t`, processor will execute two instructions on x86_32 and four on x86_16, both of them suboptimal.

Comment: I am not sure this is posible with a standard C compiler. Each new platform with larger register size would probably have a different ABI, and need a whole new C compiler. That's just my impression though. I think it'd be tricky enough to add native 128 bit storage to C. I may be mistaken though.

Comment: In that case, you can't determine it portably — there's no recognition of number of instructions in the C standard.  C is sometimes castigated as 'portable assembler', but if you need to worry about assembler cycles, you don't use C — you use assembler.

Comment: @User - the wording "What is the best and most portable way to ..." implicitly assumes there is a portable way that is best (by whatever measure).  Running a test suite and determining the best of tested options that a platform has to offer based on measurements, or reading documentation for a given platform, are valid approaches, but but they are not portable (a test suite may not test every option on a given platform, platform-specific documentation is non-portable by definition) and it is a philosophical question whether they are "best".

Comment: @Dmitry: you could in theory have a compiler that used: `unsigned char` for 8 bits, `unsigned short` for 16 bits, `unsigned int` for 32 bits, `unsigned long` for 64 bits, `unsigned long long` for 128 bits, and `uintmax_t` for 256 bits before you run out of unique standard names for the types — couldn't you?  I'm not sure how much code would run out of the box on such a system, but it could be a plausible architecture.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I want to allow it, but I need a fallback portable code and a higher-level interface to use the library.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I prefer the terms uint8_t, uint16_t, uint32_t, uint64_t, uint128_t, ... the system decides  the preferred size for operation speed by uint_fastX_t where X is minimum bits required. I abandoned using int/char in bit specific operations in hopes that using them less gives more flexibility to get rid of those ugly constructs and replace them with byte, word, dword, qword which are more reliable. I only use char for ascii and int for lazy alternative to int_fast8/16_t If the system decides 1024 bits is fastest, int_fast32_t will be 1024 bits, but I don't care.

Comment: as you do not know such standard type, why do you talk about add-with-carry instruction for 128-bit types?

Comment: @Serge C99 standard doesn't prohibit define `uintmax_t` as a 128 bit value on platforms that support them. x86 with SSE2 support them, so on some weird implementations `uintmax_t` can be a 128 bit value for this platform. In this case, it will be suboptimal because it prevents the compiler to do some optimizations like the add-with-carry that I commented.

Comment: I mean, if you are talking about arbitrary precision math implemented in C99 standard C, then why do you mention add-with-carry asm instruction at all?

Comment: @Serge It's true that C99 doesn't support it directly, but compilers or programmers can optimize the underlying implementation using it, as long as they maintain the compatibility with the standard C99 interface.

Comment: I doubt: this is quite rare case to implement an optimizer that detect that code written in C checks if the addition of two values would cause an overflow and then convert two unrelated additions into the sequence of add a[0],b[0]; addc a[1],b[1] (read this as a pseudo-code, not as any particular asm notation)

Comment: @Serge Automated compilers are not the only way to compile a program specified via C99 source code. There are also *human compilers*, capable to do this optimization without problems. Their only restriction is to fulfill the contract specified in the source code, so we need a way to allow these *human compilers* to optimize his code to the target platform without breaking standard assumptions. For this case we need a type that directly corresponds to the processor integer register size.

Comment: for human compilers I offered the solution in my first comment and the  answer proposes nearly the same. The experienced coder would implement a few variations of the same thing keeping in mind any differences between a few commonly used architectures. If you say 'fully portable' then there is no place to mention 'add-with-carry'

Comment: @Serge It is true that an human compiler can use any type he wants, but there must be C99 header files defining structs and functions with some types in them to allow his code to be usable by C99 programs. Further, there can be a mixed automated/human generated code (to be honest, human optimized code is only needed in a few critical places, if needed at all), in witch we need to ensure that both use the same type. With the current standard the only way to ensure this is by using macros. This lack of expressiveness is a language drawback...

Comment: There is no excellence in the Universe ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the best and most portable way to obtain the larger and faster integer type on every platform that has a C99 standard compiler?

Compile a test program with all candidate types, run it, time it, select the fastest and then compile your application.

In other words, finding the fastest type is done at *configure-time*, not at compile-time. This has the additional benefit of using the fastest type even if the implementation lies about it in `stdint.h`.

Comment: There is no physical reason that doesn't allow us to do it at compile time. It is a political (standardization) one. Anyway , it seems that you can't do it in C99 at compile time, so I will accept this answer as a valid one.